# Inverse-variance weighting non related to meta-analysis?

Tags: variance, mean, outliers

I've been reading about inverse-variance weighting and every reference I find to it is related to meta-analysis. However, I wonder if inverse-variance weighting can be used to reduce the bias produced by outliers in highly variant data.

Say we have a random variable $X$ containing a subset $X_o \in X$ consisting of outliers (let us not dwelve under which criteria it is established that some $x \in X$ is an outlier). Furthermore, assume this outliers skew $X$ to the right (they are far greater than most $x \in X$.) Then the arithmetic mean of $X$ will be biased and skewed to the right as well, and hence will not be very representative. E.g., if $X=[1, 2, 3, 15]$ then $\mu_x= 5.25$.

Couldn't we use inverse-variance weighting to reduce the bias produced by outliers when computing the mean? If each $x_i \in X$ is assigned a weight $w_i$ that is the reciprocal of some point-specific variance measure, such as

$$\frac{\sum_{x \neq x_i}|x_i-x|}{n-1}$$

then outliers would contribute less to the average and hence that average would be more representative. Using the same example $X$ as before, and the variance measure used  as example, the weighted mean now gives $\mu_{x_w}\approx3.30$, which is less skewed.

Clearly, this has nothing to do with meta-analysis. And yet it seems like a reasonably use of inverse-variance weighting.